# Find the age of son from sum of father & son's age?

Tags: math, algebra

The sum of John's age and his father's age is 45. Five years ago, John father's age was six times John's age. How old is John now?

Given Answers:
a) 8,
b) 9,
c) 10,
d) 12

Any brief help appriciated

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is maths based and has nothing programming specific.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let us take John's present age to be variable x.
Five years ago, John's age was x - 5.
According to the problem, his father's age was six times John's age. (Five years ago)

Therefore, the age of father five years ago will be 6(x - 5) = 6x - 30.
If the age five years ago was 6x - 30 (Father), now, which is five years after, his father's age will be (6x - 30) + 5

= 6x - 30 + 5

= 6x - 25.

From the problem we know that the sum of his father's present age and John's present age is 45, from which we conclude that (6x - 25)_Father's present age + x_John's present age = 45.
Equation : 
(6x - 25) + x = 45

6x - 25 + x = 45

7x - 25 = 45

7x -25 + 25 = 45 + 25

7x = 70

7x ÷ 7 = 70 ÷ 7

x = 10

Therefore, x, which was supposed to be John's age, is 10 years.
John is 10 years old ...... Answer - c) 10

Comment: Thanks @KSJ10. I need help in an another following question: If a=2, b=4 and c=3 then 2ac[(2b+3c)-c] is?
Given options:
A) 11,
B) 51,
C) 132,
D) 12

Comment: Sorry for so late reply.

Comment: Here we start off by putting the values in the place where they should be.

Comment: So, the equation is : 2 × 2 × 3  × [(2 × 4 + 3 × 3) - 3]                                            = 4 × 3 × [(8 + 9) - 3]                                                                                       = 12 × [17 - 3]                                                                                                = 12 × 14                                                                                                        = 168

Comment: well i can't answer over here

Comment: Thanks @KSJ10, when you get time please see this question "http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2040926/how-many-kg-fresh-figs-is-required-to-get-12-kg-dried-figs"